# The Type or Namespace name 'DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandlerArgs' does not exist in 'System.Windows.Forms'

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView and overloaded event handlers:

MyView.Designer.cs

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView grdAssignedProjects;
this.grdAssigned.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.grdAssigned_DoubleClick);
this.grdAssigned.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(this.grdAssigned_DataError); // Compile error
```

and then the handlers:

MyView.cs

```
private void grdAssigned_DoubleClick (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    ... stuff ...
 }

 private void grdAssigned_DataError(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandlerArgs eventArgs) // Compile error 
    ... stuff ...
 }
```

I get a compile error on the line indicated above:

> The Type or Namespace name 'DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandlerArgs' does not exist in 'System.Windows.Forms'

Yet, the doc for DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs shows that the namespace is `System.Windows.Forms`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerroreventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2

So the DoubleClick overload is fine, but not the DataError. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The type exists. Most likely you're missing a library reference or namespace declaration. Had you created a Winforms application the correct libraries, namespaces and references would be added by Visual Studio itself

Comment: Check what the error message actually says: `System.WIndows.Forms`. Capital `I`.

Comment: The Capital I is just a typo on my part (my apologies). Based on your comment I did a search on all the code and` DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandlerArgs` has not been used in this code before, so you must be correct in that a library reference is missing. What library do I need to add?

Comment: No way. That class was added back in 2005 with .NET 2.0. People would have noticed if there was any issue. Just add the [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-2.0) from the Toolbox and let the designer add references and events. How did you add that `DataGridView` anyway?

Comment: It's `...EventArgs`, not `...EventHandlerArgs`

Comment: @StephanBauer: you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandlerArgs` does not exist because the correct name is `DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs`, without "Handler".
So just a typo here..

Comment: "Just a typo" should lead you to the close options, not the answer box.